# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:[2.2.0]

Tags: android, gradle

При попытке синхронизации Gradle файла появилась ошибка

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:[2.2.0]
```

При выполнении дествия Build -> Clean project Появляется следующая ошибка

```
Could not find any matches for androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:[2.2.0] as no versions of androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime are available.
Required by:
    project :app > androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0
    project :app > androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0
Search in build.gradle files
```

Мой Gradle файл

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.3"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3"
    annotationProcessor  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    annotationProcessor  "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

В подобных вопросах рекомендуют обновить версию библиотеки, но студия не предлагает мне обновиться.

Answer (score 1):

Я понял в чем причина данной ошибки. Из-за санкций я могу юзать гугловские библиотеки только через VPN, который я благополучно забыл подключить.